# Problem with .ENV variable in docker image but not locally

Tags: docker, axios, environment-variables, nestjs

When running my nestjs app locally, i have a long .env private key variable, this key includes '\n' and other characters. this works perfectly when running locally and passing the key to an axois request body param. But when I test the route with the deployed image on was fargate using an .env in a secure bucket (the .env is identical) I get a BAD REQUEST 400 returned from my ayrshare request parameter issue.

When I run the image locally and download the .env from the bucket and run it I get the same issue. I have logged the PK and it's there and seems to be the exact same. I have no idea what might be happening or how to fix it, have been stuck on it for a couple days. anyone have any ideas?